# check value in the array in Vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have one array **app.getValue("Model.OutputArrays.FinalCompleteFileName_Array")="6F_HMBDConfig_978153ewnqsettgb73171_1219_31_640.pdf","6F_HMBDConfig_978153ewnqsettgb73171_1219_31_640.pdf","6F_HMBDConfig_978153ewnqsettgb73171_1219_31_640.pdf"**

I have to apply a condition or check in the array if **pdfname** is already exist in the array then it will go to under If condition. But for the below code pdfname is always going to the Else condition even the pdfname is present in the filename_array.

please correct me where i am going wrong.

```
sub run

pdfname = "6F_HMBDConfig_978153ewnqsettgb73171_1219_31_640.pdf"
filename_array = app.getValue("Model.OutputArrays.FinalCompleteFileName_Array")
TestArray = Split(filename_array , ",")
  For i=Lbound(TestArray) to Ubound(TestArray)
    If StrComp(TestArray(i), pdfname , 1) = 0 Then
      CompareStrings = True
     MsgBox("Found " & pdfname & " at index " & i)
    Else
     CompareStrings = False
     MsgBox "String not found!"
End If
Next

end sub
```

Comment: app.getValue - is it a string or array? If its an array, you can simply use [`Filter`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_filter.asp) to check if the required pdf value is present or not - hence directly using it in `If` condition without having to loop through the entire array. And if its a string, use InStr directly

Comment: @PankajJaju I think it is a string. That's why he is performing the split operation to get an array containing the filenames

Comment: Its confusing because he said its an array and the way he represented the data, it looks like an array. But then he used split. So not sure if his code or data is correct.

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar Did the solution help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the app.getvalue is returning a string containing the pdf file names **with each name surrounded by double-quotes**. So, remove those double-quotes as shown below and run the code again.

Replace this:

```
filename_array = app.getValue("Model.OutputArrays.FinalCompleteFileName_Array")
```

With:

```
filename_array = replace(trim(app.getValue("Model.OutputArrays.FinalCompleteFileName_Array")),"""","")
```

**Alternative Solution:**

If you don't want to use the `replace` method, you can modify your `if` condition to use the `instr` method instead of `strcomp` method as shown below:

```
If InStr(1,TestArray(i), pdfname , 1) > 0 Then
      CompareStrings = True
     MsgBox("Found " & pdfname & " at index " & i)
    Else
     CompareStrings = False
     MsgBox "String not found!"
End If
```